# Clojure : function returns nil rather an evaluated expression

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have written a function that sums the members of a list.  Pretty straightforward, newbie stuff, but for some reason it returns nil, and I am at a loss as to why: this should be a no-brainer.  The implementation and function call follow.

The implementation:

```
(defn add-list-members
  ([x] (add-list-members x 0))
  ([x total]
   (if (= (count x) 2)
     (+ (first x) (first (rest x)) total))
   (if (= (count x) 1)
     (+ (first x) total))
   (if (> (count x) 2)
     (recur (rest (rest x)) (+ (+ (first x) (first (rest x))) total)))))
```

The call to the function:

```
(println "our total is: " (add-list-members '(2 23 33 14 33 134 9000 98993)))
```

Meanwhile, I have a debugging version with print statements added, and I have been able to verify that the implementation works as it should.

Debugging version:

```
(defn add-list-members-debug
  ([x] (add-list-members-debug x 0))
  ([x total]
   (println ">>> our list now: " x)
   (println ">>> our total now: " total)
   (if (= (count x) 2)
     (println "outcome 2 : " (+ (first x) (first (rest x)) total)))
   (if (= (count x) 1)
     (println "outcome 1 : " (+ (first x) total)))
   (if (> (count x) 2)
     (recur (rest (rest x)) (+ (+ (first x) (first (rest x))) total)))))
```

Call to debugging version:

```
(add-list-members-debug '(2 23 33 14 33 134 9000 98993))
```

The development tools I am using are Vim plugged into the Leiningen REPL.  Any hints about what I'm doing wrong here would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean "null" rather than "nil"?

Comment: The output from the problem version is: "our total is: nil"

Comment: No, `nil` is what Clojure often returns when there's nothing else to return.

Comment: Another person using vim with Clojure!  Now I know that there are at least two of us. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are wrong, or at least suboptimal, and you have no base case that returns `total`.  (About the parentheses: Your indentation, which is correct given the parentheses, shows this: Each `if` is on the same level; none of them are in the "else" position.)  Here's one correct version:

```
(defn add-list-members
  ([x] (add-list-members x 0))
  ([x total]
   (if (= (count x) 0)
     total
     (if (= (count x) 2)
       (+ (first x) (first (rest x)) total)
       (if (= (count x) 1)
         (+ (first x) total)
         (if (> (count x) 2)
           (recur (rest (rest x)) (+ (+ (first x) (first (rest x))) total))))))))
```

You get `nil` as the return value because when the last `if` test fails, it goes to the `else` clause, which in this case is an empty end of a list, i.e. `nil`.

However, the multiple `if`s can be replaced with one `cond`.  You can also use `ffirst` for `(first (first`, `fnext` instead of `(first (rest`, and `nnext` instead of `(rest (rest`.  It would also be more idiomatic to use a predicate such as `empty?` instead of checking for `count` equal to 0; I used `count` for the base case simply to maintain the parallel with your existing code.  The simplest version might be:

```
(defn add-list-members [x] (apply + x))
```

You could also use `reduce` for a very simple version.  You may just have wanted to experiment with `recur`, though.

(Well, you *could* do it without using the embedded `else` clauses, as in your original, but I wouldn't recomment it, and you still need the empty sequence base case.  When you put multiple separate expressions in an function definition, each one of them always gets executed. This is inefficient and, I feel, error prone.  Using multiple, separate expressions in a function definition makes sense when you're creating side effects--e.g. adding print statements for debugging.)

Comment: OK -- understood.  Thank you very much for the explanation plus pointers.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I thought -- erroneously -- that the function return was implicit for the passed if tests.  I really had no right to think that, but I'm susceptible to wishful thinking sometimes.  Thanks, again.

Comment: Note also that `fnext` is just `second`. I suppose I might use it in some contexts where `ffirst` is also relevant, but usually it's a pretty rare function to use.

Answer (score 6):

You used `if` in a wrong way. Consider the following code: I intentionally simplified the code to make it clear what happens.

```
(defn xxx [v]
  (if (= (count v) 1) "one")
  (if (= (count v) 2) "two")
  (if (> (count v) 2) "more"))
```

What happens if you run `(xxx [1])`? Perhaps you expect the code will return `"one"`, however, it returns `nil`. Why?

Function returns value of its last expression, in this case, the last line `(if (> (count v) 2) "more")`. If you pass `[1]`, the first `if` expression returns `"one"`, which is ignored. The second `if` will return `nil`, which is also ignored. The third and the last will return `nil`, which is the return value of the function.

Perhaps the simplest way to compute sum of elements is:

```
(defn add-elements [xs] (apply + xs))
```

or

```
(defn add-elements [xs] (reduce + xs))
```

Your code can be reimplemented in much simpler way:

```
(defn add-elements
  ([xs] (add-elements xs 0))
  ([xs total] (if (empty? xs) total
                (recur (rest xs) (+ total (first xs))))))
```

Comment: Thanks much for your comments and the illustration of the simplified implementation.